# SQL Server 2008 r2 how to split column values to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to split column values to raw values e.g:

```
Col1            col2
1               james
1               gold
1               james@gmail.com
2               john
2               def
2               def@gmail.com
```

col1 values keep on changing  to thousands.

results:

```
col1            col2      col3      col4
1               james     gold      james@gmail.com 
2               john      def       ef@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

This will not guarantee the order of the values among the columns, as the table doesnt have a column to show the order of the columns..If you have a column, like that, you could change select 0 with that column

```
with cte as(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() 
         over(partition by Col1 order by (select 0))as rn from Table1)  
select * from cte
pivot(
   Max(COL2) FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3] )  
   )P
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f3e2/1)